# Tensorflow tf.split() list index out of range?

Tags: tensorflow

Here's the codes:

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3,4])
b = tf.constant([4])
c = tf.split(a, tf.squeeze(b))
```

then, it turns out to be wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jeff/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1203, in split
    num = size_splits_shape.dims[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) state,

> If num_or_size_splits is a tensor, size_splits, then splits value into len(size_splits) pieces. The shape of the i-th piece has the same size as the value except along dimension axis where the size is size_splits[i].

Note that `size_splits` needs to be slicable.

However when you `squeeze(b)`, because it has only one element in your example, it returns a scalar that has no dimension. A scalar cannot be sliced :

```
b_ = tf.squeeze(b)
b_[0] # error
```

Hence your error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to split a in 4 pieces now?

Comment: `tf.split(a, 4)`, without wrapping the number in a tensor.